# MCU clamping diodes

Tags: microcontroller, diodes, microcontroller

As a simple and cheap way of protecting my MCU against higher than 3.3V logic inputs, can I use for low speed data transfers some resistors on the data lines? In theory, these should act in tandem with the pin diodes inside the MCU to clamp the voltage. But will it work in practice? Logic shifter chips aren't an option due to space and cost constraints.

Comment: what speed is the bus and does it have pull ups?  If its something like an I2C bus you can do this with 1 transistor for each line (data/clk).  You do need pull ups on both the 5V and 3.3V sides however.

Comment: It's a low speed UART, not faster than 19200 bps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the pins have clamp diodes, you need only a series resistor to limit the current. You can see in the application note [AN521](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00521c.pdf) from microchip that it connect the pin of the microcontroller directly in the AC.

I have used a voltage divider to connect a PIC to a GPRS module with a speed higher than 19,200 and had no problem.

Answer (score 4):

Sparkfun have a good summary of [ways to connect 5V and 3.3V devices](http://www.sparkfun.com/commerce/tutorial_info.php?tutorials_id=65).

As well as using diodes, you could consider MOSFETs or inline resistors.